# Using the jackknife method in permutation tests

Tags: multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, canonical-correlation, jackknife

We aim to employ a permutation test to evaluate the significance of the relationship between two datasets using Sparse Canonical Correlation Analysis (SCCA) for a specific level of sparsity. To achieve this, we randomize the two datasets, ensuring that the relationship between them varies and becomes stochastic with each iteration. We then compare this distribution with the correlation coefficient derived from the full dataset. My question is: Can I utilize the jackknife estimation of correlation as a substitute for the full dataset when comparing it to the distribution?